# как проверить что в словаре что-то есть?

Tags: c#, словари, if

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    if (dict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
    }
}
```

Есть словарь со вложенным словарем. Как написать условие, которое бы сразу проверяло наличие данных в словаре и срабатывало бы, если в словарях что-то есть, и не срабатывало, если в них ничего нет?

Comment: `.TryGetValue()` в помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно узнать, содержит ли словарь элементы, можно использовать его свойство `Count`

```cs
if (dict.Count > 0) {
  // словарь не пуст - содержит элемент(ы)
} else {
  // словарь пуст - не содержит элементов
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Проверить наличие ключа в словаре:

```cs
public bool ContainsKey(TKey key);
```

Пример:

```cs
if (dict.ContainsKey(5))
{
    Console.WriteLine("dict[5] существует");
}
```

#### Получить значение по ключу в словаре, если ключ в нём содержится:

```cs
public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out TValue value);
```

Данный метод нужен что бы не делать поиск ключа дважды когда тебе надо его получить, но ты не уверен в его существовании.

Пример использования:

```cs
if (dict.TryGetValue(6, out var value))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"dict[6] == {value}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("dict[6] не существует");
}
```

#### Проверить наличие значения в словаре:

```cs
public bool ContainsValue(TValue value);
```

Отлично работает если TValue является [типом значений](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) (например `int`, `string`, `struct` и другие примитивные типы)

Таким образом для

```cs
Dict<string, int> dict { {"key", 5} };
```

```cs
dict.ContainsValue(5);
```

Вернёт `true`

Однако с [ссылочными типами](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) (такие как наши объекты и т. п.) есть **нюанс**

`ContainsValue(TValue value)` для ссылочных типов использует `value.Equals` метод для поиска нужного объекта.

А по умолчанию (для `object` и всего, что его наследует) он сравнивает ссылки на этот объект. Таким образом для класса

```cs
class Test
{
    public int v = 5;
}

var dict = new Dictionary<int, Test>()
{
    {5, new Test() {v = 5 } },
};
```

код

```cs
if (dict.ContainsValue(dict[5]))
    Console.WriteLine("true");
else
    Console.WriteLine("false")
```

выведет true, ведь `dict[5]` и `dict[5]` это один и тот же объект

Однако этот код

```cs
if (dict.ContainsValue(new Test() { v = 5 }))
    Console.WriteLine("true");
else
    Console.WriteLine("false");
```

выведет false, ведь new создаёт **новый** объект.

*P. S.: С типами значений, даже при прописывании new всё работать будет, т. к. так устроена память*

Если же мы хотим, что бы код выше заработал нам необходимо переопределить метод `Equals`:

```cs
class Test
{
    public int v = 5;
    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        if (obj is Test test) // Если тип второго объекта такой же
            return test.v == v; // то возвращаем true, если v совпадают
        return base.Equals(obj); // иначе стандартная проверка
    }
}
```

Теперь код

```cs
if (dict.ContainsValue(new Test() { v = 5 }))
    Console.WriteLine("Test {v=5} существует");
```

сработает

#### Получить ключ/значение элемента с помощью linq и своего компаратора:

Мы так же можем использовать `linq` методы для поиска. Таким образом мы можем найти значение используя не конкретное значение, а компаратор. Допустим у нас есть словарь:

```cs
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>()
{
    {
        "key1",
        new()
        {
            { "kkey1", "ok!" }
        }
    },
    {
        "key2",
        new()
        {
            { "kkey2", "ok2!" }
        }
    }
};
```

Что эквивалентно этому в json:

```json
{
    key1: {
        kkey1: 'ok!'
    },
    key2: {
        kkey2: 'ok2!'
    }
}
```

И мы хотим получить такой ключ внешнего словаря, у которого во внутреннем словаре имеется значение `ok2!` (в нашем случае это `key2`)

Это можно реализовать так:

```cs
// Ищем первое вхождение, у которого у значения имеется значение ok2!
var key = dict.First(e => e.Value.ContainsValue("ok2!")).Key;
```

Сюда вы можете поставить любую функцию, которая будет проверять значение (а может даже и ключ).

Вообще `linq` имба, вот ещё пример, где мы очищаем все вхождения, где ключ == значение:

*Тут так же можно увидеть, как преобразовать `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<...>>` в `Dictionary<...>`*

```cs
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "a", "a" },
    { "b", "c" }
};
var filteredDict = dict.Where(e => e.Key != e.Value).ToDictionary(v => v.Key, v => v.Value);
// filteredDict == {b: "c"}
```

Comment: Замечания: 1. Всеж слишком много того, что не нужно, и может даже не понадобиться читателю (не забываем, что SO это не форум, а база вопросов, где читатели разные). Стоит писать что-то по типу "для этого есть методы ... и ...", описав что они делают и примеры использования, на этом как бы все, ответ полный будет, но у вас и LINQ непойми зачем, который дергает все теж методы, и про сравнение классов, даже JSON непойми зачем... 2. Если перечитать вопрос, то там идет больше речь про "сли в словарях что-то есть", а не конкретный объект. 3. `Equals` лучше реализовывать с интерфейсом и хэшем.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ 1) Вопрос слишком общий. Там не сказано что именно. Сказано только про "наличие данных в словаре", для этого я и привязал `linq`, `.First(...)` и т. д. При этом я всё сортировал на главы, что бы читатель мог прочитать только про то, что ему надо. 2) да нет, вопрос про наличие конкретный данных, будь то наличие ключа, значения и т. п. 3) Смотря какой объект + могут возникнуть коллизии, которые напрочь сломают словарь, да и вопрос уже не про это. Более сложная реализация могла бы запутать читателя.

Comment: внесу поправку: Наличие любых данных(пустой, или же что-то в нем есть)

Comment: Ну, я не вижу там "слишком общий", я вижу конкретный код с простым условием `if`, и конкретный вопрос "что-то есть, и не срабатывало, если в них ничего нет".  А вот ответ да, слишком общий. Но дело ваше. "да и вопрос уже не про это." - о чем и речь, к чему это в ответе мне не ясно...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну так у меня тоже if вместе с linq используется))) Проверка ключа, значения и проверка наличия элемента через кастомный компаратор. Единственное, к чему я бы сам придрался это последние пару строчек где я использую `.Where()`, но это занимает буквально пару строк и просто как наставление... под `Данные в словаре` можно многое подмять

Comment: Не, дело ваше, считаете этот ответ хорошим, ок. Просто SO любит коротко и по делу, знаю по себе) "можно многое подмять" - если невнимательно прочитать, да. Вон я как видите тоже поперек вопрос и понял, что нужен один объект, а перечитав еще раз увидел, что речь про любые данные, условно пустой или нет словарь (и как я понял вложенный), да и автор вон выше тоже подтвердил это. Так что, на данный момент ваш вопрос не по теме.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ладно сдаюсь, тут вы правы)